# What's a word for someone whose personality or character changes a lot and get more affected than others by other's company or influential people?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example: He is a _ type of person

Comment: Your question suggests someone susceptible to influence. But I'm not sure there is a single word to describe everything you want to convey, and context might be very important. I know that often people associate the sign Gemini with the traits you mention and "Geminian" is a word in the Oxford-American dictionary. However, it would sound stilted or arrogant in general use, and would very likely confuse your reader.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer **impressionable**, as suggested by @KarimTabet, but I will add **gullible** and **credulous** to the possibilities he suggested. From Lexico:

> **[gullible](https://www.lexico.com/definition/gullible)**: Easily persuaded to believe something; credulous.

> **[credulous](https://www.lexico.com/definition/credulous)**: Having or showing too great a readiness to believe things.

"Someone whose personality or character changes a lot and get [sic] more affected than others by company or influential people" is more **impressionable**, gullible**, or credulous** than others.

Answer (score 2):

The person's personality would be described as [**malleable**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/malleable):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **2 a** : capable of being altered or controlled by outside forces or influences

Using it with the example sentence:

> He is a *malleable* type of person.

Or, more naturally:

> He is weak-willed, and has a *malleable* personality that is easily influenced and changed by others.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't fit your sentence well, but the person could be considered a ***chameleon*** ([M/W def 2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chameleon))

> a person who often changes his or her beliefs or behavior in order to please others or to succeed

By analogy to an actual chameleon, which changes coloration to match its surroundings.